# Custom forms for custom post types in D7

Tags: 7, forms

I am sub-theming Bartik and have a content type called "support_query" with 3 fields... "title" (which comes with all content types), "field_support_body" and "field_support_date" (which is a simple date field from the Date module).

I would like to create a custom form so users can send me queries of this custom post type... what's a good way to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your content type's form, customized to suit the basic user.

You'll have to give the allowed users role the right permission (like `Create *the content type*').

Then you'll have to change the form to mask all irrelevant information. There are many ways to do this :

- Implement a module with a `hook_form_alter'. Flexible but involves coding.
- Use a module or a combination to achieve the same goal. [This one](http://drupal.org/project/rules_formshttp://drupal.org/project/rules_forms) for example seems to be interesting.

Comment: Argh..you got in just as I was about to click submit :-p

Comment: Not fast enough, grasshopper ^_^.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...so I would need to create my own module just to alter this form for anonymous users?

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  Just don't give anonymous users permission to do things such as set menu items etc. (i.e. the stuff that's in the admin side of the node/add form)

Comment: It could be enough, but it could not. If you start with Chapabu method and it suits your needs, stick with it. It's the right way to start anyway. But know that writing code is often needed to really make forms behave as you want.

Comment: I do @Countzero , I actually need to do some validation and I'd like to save the fields with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You could just give anonymous users permission to create nodes of this content type.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Give users permission to create *support_query* nodes.
2. Give the node/add form an alias (you can set this at
   `admin/config/search/path`) for the *support request* content type
   (for example, alias it to *www.example.com/support-request*)

After this you can do some pretty useful things...here are a few examples:

- Use [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create reports of submitted support requests,
- Use the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to set flags on the content (e.g. received, assigned, in progress, completed to name but a few)
- Set some [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) up to e-mail the user who submitted the support request when it is flagged at each different stage (e.g. e-mail a user when their request has been assigned to an employee)

Answer (score -2):

Use [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a
>   submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a
>   notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or
>   other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic
>   statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its
>   features.

Comment: The OP has said that this data is already set up as a content type.  Using Webform is not really an answer.

Comment: Yes but it is the best way to make such a thing.

Comment: "Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal.".  The OP isn't making a survey - he is making a support request system.  Also, the flexibility of what you can do with nodes over webform submissions makes nodes a MUCH better solution in this use case.

Webform is a great module, but I personally don't think it fits this use case very well.

Comment: I considered using webform but unfortunately I don't want to just list these webform results within the support query view, I want the form to actually save the data AS a support_query

Comment: Have you tried this module http://drupal.org/project/support ?

Comment: If you prefer using webform. Set permissions so that user cant view results. And webform will save data in db for sure.